# Laravel: Checking Specific Column Pivot Table

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a Many-to-Many relationship where there is an addional value column on the table. How do I pick that value? So...

```
pivot_table
- user_id
- something_id
- value
```

Model `User`:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Something', 'user_something')->withPivot('value');
```

Now, I would like to get the value for one user where the something id is 2.

Something like this:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->something->whereSomethingId(2)->pivot->value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$user->something->find(2)->pivot->value;
```

Since `something` is a collection so we may use `find($id)` method to get an item by it's `id`. Also, you may use `filter(callback)` method to filter the collection using a loop and running the callback (passed in `filter` method as argument) in every loop, for example:

```
$user->something->filter(function($item){
    // $item is an object from the collection
    // So, you may use: $item->pivot->value
});
```

You may also read [this article](http://heera.it/extend-laravel-eloquent-collection-object#.Uz2DmfmSySo).